# Need help understanding implementation of mutex with test_and_set

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, locking, mutual-exclusion, test-and-set

The book Operating System Principles by Silberschatz, Galvin, and Gagne  has the following implementation for atomic operations of  test_and_set

```
boolean test_and_set(boolean *target) {
    boolean rv = *target;
    *target = true;
    return rv;
}
```

They declared a global variable lock initialized to 0 and used the following implementation of the mutex for each process

```
do {
    while(test_and_set(&lock))
        ; // do nothing
        // critical section
    lock = false;
        // remainder section
} while(true);
```

Now, let's consider the situation when process P0 is implementing the critical section and process P1 is stuck at the while loop. Consider the following order of execution then

```
//lock = true initially because P0 is in critical section
P1 boolean rv = *target; //rv = true, lock = true
//P0 now completed its critical section and is ready to leave the lock
P0 lock = false //rv = true, lock = false
P1 *target = true; //rv = true, lock = true
P1 return rv; // returns true
```

So, the process P0 or any other as a matter of fact cannot enter the critical section forever.
How does this handle this case then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in your description and such a situation would lead to a deadlock.
But what you are missing is that `test_and_set` must be an **atomic** operation. This is not a `test` followed by a `set` but a *unique* unbreakable operation that performs both.

It is generally implemented by processors with an instruction that 1/ forbids out of order execution, 2/ waits until the pipeline and the memory queue of the processor are empty, 3/ reads the memory in a register and 4/ sets the memory word. The read/write memory cannot be interrupted, no thread swap can happen and memory access is forbidden to other processors.

On risc processors, there is a similar mechanism. You first perform a special load that watches accesses to memory (frequently called `load locked`) and it is followed by a special store that will fail is any access has been done on the memory location (`store conditional`).

This way, one can be certain that only one thread has access to the memory during the the `test_and_set` and the situation that you describe cannot happen.

```
//lock = true initially because P0 is in critical section
P1 boolean rv = *target; //rv = true, lock = true
//P0 now completed its critical section and is ready to leave the lock
// BUT P0 MUST WAIT THE COMPLETION OF THE TAS.
// NO THREAD SWAP CAN HAPPEN AND ACCESS TO *target IS LOCKED
// DELAYED UNTIL END OF TAS P0 lock = false //rv = true, lock = false
P1 *target = true; //rv = true, lock = true
P1 return rv; // returns true
//NOW WE CAN DO
P0 lock = false //rv = true, lock = false
// AND LOCK IS PROPERLY UNSET
// ON NEXT ITERATION OF THE SPINLOCK WHILE, P1 WILL GET IT.
```

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of 'atomically'. I misunderstood the sentence "Thus, if two test_and_set() instructions are executed simultaneously (each on a different CPU), they will be executed sequentially in some arbitrary order." to mean that 
 the restriction is only on multiple test_and_set and not on other instructions. Thanks for such a wonderful explanation